# How do I open a single PowerPoint file in two windows?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

Does anyone how to open a single PowerPoint file in two separate windows?

For example, I have two PowerPoint windows open and they both have `help.ppt` open. In one window is slide #1 and on the other window is slide #10.

The purpose of this is so that I don't have to navigate back and forth between different slides.

Adobe Reader has this functionality - click on Window -> New Window and you'll have two windows for the exact same file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

View, New Window in PPT 2003 (and perhaps previous).  View | Window | New Window in PPT 2007 and 2010.

Both give you a new window onto the current presentation so you can view slide sorter in one, slides in another or just different slides in different winows.

Comment: How is this not the accepted answer? With editing enabled, PowerPoint 2010 very nicely provides the "New Window" button in the Window section of the View ribbon.

Comment: I accepted the answer a while back and don't use power point much anymore. Does this work? Can anyone confirm? If so, I'll change the accepted answer to this

Comment: This works great for Powerpoint 2010.

Comment: Still works in 2022 with Powerpoint 365.

Comment: Bonus: in more recent versions of PowerPoint you can use the Search feature (Alt + Q) on windows and simply type window → "New Window". Voilà!

Answer (score 5):

Make a copy of the file and open that copy in another instance of Powerpoint.

This assumes you don't need the file and its copy to be linked in any way, so keep track of any changes.

Comment: Agree with jonsca, just copy it...

Comment: +1 It may not be technically be the same file, but much easier.

Comment: No tracking changes necessary. As answered below, it is possible to open a _single_ power point file in two windows, which was OP's original question.

Comment: @cody.codes I upvoted that answer way back when.  The OP commented that he was reconsidering deselecting this as the answer but never did.

Answer (score 4):

First, this is REALLY stupid that Microsoft did not just allow multiple copies in PowerPoint, and make this easy. So it is not just you.

You can go to Start>Programs>Microsoft Office, and hold the SHIFT key down, and right-click on "Microsoft Office PowerPoint 2007".

Choose "Run as" and choose a different user, who can open the file. Then click Office Button>Open and navigate to the file.

I tested this successfully.

I like Jonsca's comment that just copying the file seems easier.

Comment: Creative solution. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can open two instances of the same PowerPoint presentation by:

1. Open presentation in PowerPoint
2. Click **View** -> **New Window**
   [image: New window in powerpoint]
3. All done.

Answer (score 0):

Right click program at the taskbar.
However to the recent document for said files, right click it. 
Click New.

Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way to do it with a single shortcut.

1. Make sure the PowerPoint presentation is opened and it is your active window.
2. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>
3. A new window with the same PowerPoint presentation opens.

The non-shortcut version was shown here already.
https://superuser.com/a/1357038/1595974